# onchange 2 functions on 1 dropdown

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 2 functions that I would like to call from one dropdown menu.  It seems I can only get one to work, but not both.  Looking for some help sorting this out.  Here is the code, thank you.

Function 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCredit(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("credit").innerHTML="";
return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("credit").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getcredit.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementsByName('company')[0].onchange();
}
</script>
```

And here is function 2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getTerms(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("terms").innerHTML="";
return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("terms").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","customertermsdropdownquery.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementsByName('company')[0].onchange();

}

</script>
```

And here is the form dropdown that calls them.

```
<td><select name="company" onchange="getTerms(this.value);getCredit(this.value);">
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['company']."\">".$row['company']." (".$row['first']." ".$row['last'].")</option>"; } ?></select></td>
```

I use div in the form to display php.

```
<div id="terms"></div>
and
<div id="credit"></div>
```

I can get either one to work by itself, just not together.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not package them together into one function and then call that?

Comment: Well, I'm a newb so I don't know how for one.  Keeping them separate I think helps me understand my own code better.  But, I'm not opposed if it can get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Totally understandable that you want to keep them separated.  How about create a new function like this.

```
function getTermsAndCredits(value) {
   getTerms(value);
   getCredits(value);
}
```

Then in the onchange event call it like this

```
<td><select name="company" onchange="getTermsAndCredits(this.value);">
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuclearghost/b7r7W/1/) which should give you a better idea.  I don't believe it's necessary to call the onload functions as you have in your code currently.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what to use for value in each of the 3.

Comment: Ok, I tried what you wrote there.  I am experiencing the same problem though, getTerms doesn't work but getCredits does.  Sometimes (not always) getCredits displays where getTerms is supposed to.

Comment: I think it has to do with my windows onload being in both functions.  When I remove one it works but the other doesn't.

Comment: @Tom value is the name of a variable that is passed into `getTermsAndCredits` and is subsequently passed into the other functions.  I'm not sure what the purpose of calling the onchange functions is in the onload?  I'll add a fiddle so you can see it in action

Comment: When the page is loaded, I need the value of the drop down to load right away, not wait for a change.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Then just add a single onload with the call you have. Only one will be required since that will call the correct onchange function.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but doesn't work.  Somehow something is not working right.  As I said before, sometimes the getCredit displays where the getTerms is.  Don't know why.